# How to skip weekends and other gaps from MPL finance plot

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance, mplfinance

I have the following code which plots intraday stocks data.

```
import pandas as pd, mplfinance as mpf, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import yfinance as yf
yf.download(tickers='goog', start=datetime.datetime.now()-relativedelta(days=4), end= datetime.datetime.now(), interval="5m").plot(y="Close")
```

This produces the following plot as you can see it is also plotting a line through dates where no data is available. Is there anyway i can skip the days where data is not available?

[image]

As you can see

Comment: Drop all nan values in the dataframe?

Comment: `yf.download(tickers='goog', start=datetime.datetime.now()-relativedelta(days=4), end= datetime.datetime.now(), interval="5m").dropna().plot(y="Close") `. Tried this but i still got the same plot

Comment: I did check though the original data and there was no `NaN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use MPL, it will automatically handle the x-axis time series.

```
df = yf.download(tickers='goog', start=datetime.datetime.now()-relativedelta(days=4), end=datetime.datetime.now(), interval="5m")
mpf.plot(df, figratio=(8,4), type='line', style='yahoo')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a hack:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str)
df['Close'].plot(rot = 45)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Closed to @keramat answer:

```
ax = df.set_index(df.index.strftime('%m-%d %H')).plot(y='Close', rot=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]